# Resolvent properties

Tags: spectral-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ different eigenvalues $\lambda_k.$ 
Corresponding eigenvectors are denoted as $x_k$, $x_k^Tx_k =1.$ Now $A=X\Lambda X^{-1}$. Denote $Q=X^{-1}$.

Denote $R_i = x_i \cdot q_i^T.$ Where $q_i^T$ is ith row of $Q$.

How to prove that: 
1) $R_1+...+R_n=I?$

2) $(I-A)^{-1} =  \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{R_k}{1-\lambda_k}?$

Comment: How does a vector have an inverse?

Comment: I will correct that.

Comment: What is $q_i$? $Q$'s $i$th row?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Or $Q^T$ ith column.

Answer (score 2):

This decomposition might be of use:
$$
\begin{align}
(I-A)^{-1} = &\; (I-X\Lambda X^{-1})^{-1}\\
=  &\; (X(I-\Lambda)X^{-1})^{-1} \\
= &\; X(I-\Lambda)^{-1}X^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

...and note that $(I-\Lambda)^{-1}$ is easily found if $\Lambda$ is diagonal.